# What Happens to Running Full-Load Tasks During a DMS Instance Scale-Up/Down

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

In scale-up/scale-down solution for DMS Replication Instances, there are multiple instances, and each instance is monitored via CloudWatch Alarms. When an alarm is triggered, a message is sent to a topic that in turn calls a lambda to scale the instance appropriately. Eventually, the alarm sources DMS instance is either scaled to a smaller or larger instance.

We are attempting to determine the effects of the scale-up/down occurring while an attached task is in the middle of a "Full-load". The results appear to be inconsistent and documentation to this effect can't be found. Here is what has been observed.

- Restart a full load task attached to a target instance.
- Trip the alarm for that target instance via set_alarm_state.
- Very quickly, the target DMS instance state changes to "modifying" and the links in the UI are greyed out.
  While the DMS instance appears, in the UI, to be in a "Modifying" state, the Full-Load Task continues for another 5 minutes and completes.

Is this just happenstance?

Can anyone confirm if a state transition from "Available" to "Modifying" for a DMS Instance is clever enough to wait for any active "Full-Loads" to complete before rebooting or is this just some sort of latency between state changes and the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Got a clear answer over at AWS re:post. The link is below.

https://repost.aws/questions/QUqbBHWI8rTd-JuYpO-h5QMg/what-happens-to-running-full-load-tasks-during-a-dms-instance-scale-up-down